# Canonical Topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $V$ be an n-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Of course $V \cong \mathbb{R^n}$ since we can define an isomorphism
$$f:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$$

by mapping basis elements to basis elements.

But such isomorphism requires a choice of basis.

I can define a topology $\tau = \{f^{-1}(V); V \ $is open in$\ \mathbb{R^n}\}$

But is $\tau$ a canonical topology?

An isomorphism is canonical if it is defined without having to choose a basis. 
But what does canonical mean in terms topology?

In my case, I had to "choose" a basis to define an isomorphism, then use that isomorphism to define open sets. So I'm not sure if it works...

Answer (score 10):

It is a canonical topology in the following two senses:

- A priori, the topology $\tau$ depends on the choice of an isomorphism $f \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ so let's denote $\tau$ by $\tau_f$. However, if you pick a different linear isomorphism $g \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ then you have $\tau_f = \tau_g$ so in fact, the topology doesn't depend on the choice of an isomorphism. To see that, note that we can find a linear isomorphism $T \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T \circ f = g$. Since $T$ is a linear isomorphism, it is, in particular, a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the standard topology) and so a set $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $T^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. But since $g^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(T^{-1}(U))$, the resulting topologies are the same.
- You can characterize $\tau$ without any choice by saying that $\tau$ is the weakest topology on $V$ with respect to which, any linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (or even any linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$) is continuous (where the right hand side gets the usual topology). Thus
  $$ \tau = \{ T^{-1}(U) \, | U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ is open}, T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ is a linear isomorphism}\} \\
  = \{ T^{-1}(U) \, | \, U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ is open}, T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ is linear} \} \\
  = \{ T^{-1}(U) \, | \, U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m \textrm{ is open}, T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \textrm{ is linear} \} $$
  and you eliminate any "choice" by taking "all the possible choices".
  To see that the three definitions for $\tau$ coincide, let $T \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear map and let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ be an open set. We need to show that we can find an open $\tilde{U} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and a linear isomorphism $\phi \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $T^{-1}(U) = \phi^{-1}(\tilde{U})$. Choose some linear isomorphism $\phi \colon V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and write $T = (T \circ \phi^{-1}) \circ \phi$ where $T \circ \phi^{-1} \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear, hence continuous. Then
  $$ T^{-1}(U) = \phi^{-1} \left( \underbrace{\left( T \circ \phi^{-1} \right)^{-1} (U)}_{\tilde{U}} \right). $$

Comment: Really nice comment, especially point #2, which is all-too-often neglected in favor of stating point #1 alone.

Comment: In (2), must $T:V\to{\mathbb{R}}^n$ be isomorphism? Does the result hold for general linear transformation $T$?

Comment: @user5280911: Good point. Yes, in $(2)$ you can take $T^{-1}(U)$ where $T$ runs over all isomorphisms or over all linear transformations (you can even take $\mathbb{R}^m$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$). I'll add some details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may check that your topology does not depend on the choice of $f$: if you pick another basis, the open subsets will be the same.

This topology is canonical in the following sense. First, note that it makes $V$ into a **topological vector space**: the addition of vectors $V\times V\to V$ and the action $\mathbb{R}\times V\to V$ are continuous with respect to this topology. Then, any finite dimensional Hausdorff topological vector space necessarily has the topology that you described.

See an exposition in [the blog of Terence Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/locally-compact-topological-vector-spaces/).

Comment: How can a finite-dimensional real vector space be Hausdorff without an already picked topology?

Comment: I apologize for my wording! I edited my post. I mean that if we look at all topologies that make $V$ a Hausdorff topological vector space, then the canonical topology is the only possibility.